# how to add curent div on <li> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

See this [link](http://www.jsfiddle.net/hassanjaved/xhU2s/).

My problem is: when I click on  link, then I want `.current div` on `<a>` link (like that `<a class="current">`) `<a>` and `div <style>` will show like `hover`.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the code here in your post so that future visitors to SO can bask in its indented glory. It will also allow your to post an actual link to the jsfiddle.

Comment: Your writting made my mind blow to figure out what is your question. Instead of click, you want hover?

Comment: yes, when i click on a, then i want to current div on the a link. please help me

Comment: You want the `.current` *class* on the anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$('a[id^="prod"]').removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

And CSS for the `.active` class:

```
a[id^="prod"].active {
    background: #f7edda;
    color: #d2ab67;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xhU2s/7/

Comment: How is this different than the OP's fiddle in action? I do not see a difference even if I don't know what difference the OP is asking for.

Comment: this is different because the tab keeps its "hover" look when its clicked open

Comment: Ah - subtle. I missed that @ChrisM

Comment: brother, i have got one still problem here, see your Fiddle page, when we click again on a link then .active div is not remove,

Comment: you check that @Deviant ?

Comment: @HassanJaved: Yes I see, one moment.

Comment: @HassanJaved: Sorry here is the updated fiddle (removed duplicated `e.preventDefault()` - http://jsfiddle.net/xhU2s/26/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hassanjaved/xhU2s/27/ see that, first click on 2nd menu and then click on 5th menu, both 2 will be showing in .active. =(

Comment: @Deviant you check that? understand what is the problem?

Comment: are you there? brother?